# AJAX Done() function with for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, for-loop

I have a for loop that iterates through an array of 3 values (different report numbers), and sends an AJAX request for each one. I want the .done() function to behave differently for each report that is returned. However, I'm not sure how to make the report number available to the done function. If I don't pass in the report number as an argument to the done() function, then it always thinks the report number is '190', the last value in the array. If I do pass it in, as below, it shows up as undefined.

```
function runQueries(request, data) {
    var reports = ['103', '187', '190'];
    for (i=0; i < reports.length; i++) {
        var report = reports[i];
        $.ajax({
        url: request + '&reportType=' + report},
        data: data
        })
        .done(function(response, textStatus, jqXHR, report) {
            if (report === '187') {
            ...
            }
            else if (report === '190'( {
            ...
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with is `report` is changing quicker than you requests can complete. You can avoid that with a closure. Keep in mind this won't happen in order.

```
var reports = [ 1, 2, 3 ];

for( var i = 0; i < reports.length; i++ ){
    var report = reports[i];
    console.log(report);
    (function(report){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/echo/html',
        }).done(function(){
            switch( report ){
                case 3: console.log('Three!'); break;
                case 2: console.log('Two!'); break; 
                case 1: console.log('One!'); break;
            }
        });
    })(report);
}
```

Here is it in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2ArxZ/

If you don't want to create functions in your loop, you can use this then call it in the loop.

```
function getReport( report ){
  return function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/html',
    }).done(function(){
        switch( report ){
            case 3: console.log('Three!'); break;
            case 2: console.log('Two!'); break; 
            case 1: console.log('One!'); break;
        }
    })();
  }
}
```

You could also simply use `$.each` instead, but understanding closures helps out a lot so I went the long way!

Answer (score 0):

closures and scope :

```
function runQueries(request, data) {
    var reports = ['103', '187', '190'];
    for (i=0; i < reports.length; i++) {
        (function(report) {
            $.ajax({
                url: request + '&reportType=' + report},
                data: data
            }).done(function(response) {
                if (report === '187') {
                      ...
                } else if (report === '190'( {
                      ...
                }
            });
         })(reports[i]);
    }
}
```

The `done()` method is asynchronous, so by the time that fires, the loop has long since completed.

You could also just use `$.each` to do the iteration.